# How to do treeshaking with vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have vue application with vuetify.

To have treeshaking in vuetify I need to import in this way: `import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';` [according to the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte#importing).

In my vuetify application, I don't have `v-dialog`.

When I compile my app code with `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'` I can see in the dist js bundle - that have vuetify code I which I don't use (like `v-dialog`, `v-dialog--animated`).

When I compile with `import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';` I don't see un-used code (I don't see `v-dialog`).

But the downside I have to declare each component I want to use.

Is there an easy way to do tree shaking? for example, I expect from vue to search for unused code in the vuetify bundle and remove it.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this or was manual importing  your solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you import vuetify from vuetify/lib and use the VuetifyLoaderPlugin it should work.

As the docs suggest you can use a plugin file to setup vuetify, so

```
// plugins/vuetify.js
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({/*optional options here*/})
```

and on the entry file of your application

```
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

new Vue({
  vuetify
)}.$mount('#app')
```

Then you need to make sure that you are using VuetifyLoader. Here is an example config for webpack

```
// webpack.config.js

const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
  ],
}
```

[source](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#vue-config-installation)

Comment: I spent a couple of hours yesterday trying to get this to work in a Laravel 8.x project.  It won’t compile, giving this error: 

Error: [VuetifyLoaderPlugin Error]
No matching rule for vue-loader found. Make sure there is at least one root-level rule that uses vue-loader.

Has anyone encountered and solved this?

Answer (score -8):

Do you use the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)? If not, I would suggest to do so. You just need few commands:

## Install Vue CLI

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

This will globally install the Vue CLI (you'll maybe need administrator privileges)
For more information see: [Installation|Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html)

## Create you App

```
vue create my-app
```

This will setup your project for Vue.js and ask you some question. You can use the default set. After that you must change into the projects directory.

```
cd my-app
```

## Install Vuetify

```
vue add vuetify
```

This will install the Vuetify framework. You can use the default settings. After that you've a project setup with Vue.js + Vuetify. Also the default setting is to use tree-shaking, while building the app at the end.

For more details, I have [an example here](https://medium.com/@bromix/electron-application-with-vue-js-and-vuetify-f2a1f9c749b8), which also includes Electron at the end. But the steps up to conifguration of Vuetify are the same. With this setup, you automatically have tree shaking.

Comment: This is not answering my question. please read my question again.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. The documentation states, that the Vue CLI is the recommended way (I use it in all of my projects). It safes a lot of time and trouble. If you have a **webpack.config.js**, you'll need the [vuetify-loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader) and configure your webpack explained here: [a-la-carte - webpack installation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte#webpack-installation)

Only the import in the first step won't do treeshaking.

Comment: How would we go to enable treeshaking in an *old*, existing, äpp? (In this case, it even uses vue-cli.)